# orgmode, capturing original document title

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have a basic capture template:

```
("a" "Article" entry     
(file+headline "~/GitLab/Reports/Bibliography/references.org" "Article")
"* %^{Title} \n%?")
```

that asks you to fill the Title field.

Now, my question is how to automatically fill this using the title of the original document (the original #+TITLE my title). One must certainly use *sexp* with something like:

```
("a" "Article" entry     
(file+headline "~/GitLab/Reports/Bibliography/references.org" "Article")
"* %(...some elisp instructions...) \n%?")
```

The problem is that I do not find/know a function returning the title.

I mean:

```
("a" "Article" entry     
(file+headline "~/GitLab/Reports/Bibliography/references.org" "Article")
"* %(org-capture-get :original-file-nondirectory) \n%?")
```

fills with the original file name, but the equivalent for title:

```
%(org-capture-get :title)
```

does not exist.

I also try, from an org-mode file:

```
#+TITLE: Titi Toto

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(plist-get (org-export-get-environment) ':title)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Titi Toto |
```

but

```
(plist-get (org-export-get-environment) ':title)
```

does not work anymore when used in the capture template.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function that collects the title of the original file (the file visited by the current buffer when org-capture was called). If you have `org-collect-keywords` (added in
[`b4e91b7e949`](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/b4e91b7e944c900db6b8217d78011afcd2c1e62c)), you can use:

```lisp
(defun get-title (file)
  (let (title)
    (when file
      (with-current-buffer
          (get-file-buffer file)
        (pcase (org-collect-keywords '("TITLE"))
          (`(("TITLE" . ,val))
           (setq title (car val)))))
      title)))
```

Then, in the template, add:

```
%(get-title (org-capture-get :original-file))
```

If you have an older version installed, replace `(pcase ...)` with:

```
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (when (re-search-forward "^[ \t]*#\\+title:[ \t]*\\(.*\\)$" nil t)
    (setq title (match-string 1))))
```

Comment: I'd simply your elaborate `get-title` function, removing the `title` variable and changing the `pcase` form to just `(cadar (org-collect-keywords '("TITLE")))`.

Answer (score 2):

org-roam has a function that does this [here](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/blob/50cc81c76d90a3c6f23c3a281e0206d128cc8f3e/org-roam.el#L459-L464)

```lisp
(defun org-roam--extract-titles-title ()
  "Return title from \"#+TITLE\" of the current buffer."
  (let* ((prop (org-roam--extract-global-props '("TITLE")))
         (title (cdr (assoc "TITLE" prop))))
    (when title
      (list title))))

(defun org-roam--extract-global-props (props)
  "Extract PROPS from the current org buffer.
The search terminates when the first property is encountered."
  (let ((buf (org-element-parse-buffer))
        res)
    (dolist (prop props)
      (let ((p (org-element-map buf 'keyword
                 (lambda (kw)
                   (when (string= (org-element-property :key kw) prop)
                     (org-element-property :value kw)))
                 :first-match t)))
        (push (cons prop p) res)))
    res))
```

Comment: Please write your answer such that it is still useful in case your link breaks.